# How to let PyCharm find Todo items in docstrings?

Tags: pycharm, docstring, todo

I was just playing around with PyCharms TODO finder. It is a nice feature and I would like to use it more intense. However it doesn't find any todo entries that I use in my docstrings.

```py
"""
Do something.

:todo: This is my Todo-Item that is sadly not found

"""
# Todo: When I use line comments it is found.
def my_function():
    pass
```

Is there a way to configure PyCharm to find todo items in docstrings?

Comment: I dont really see the point. Why would you want to put TODO in the docstring?

Comment: It seems a good place for me to put my todo entries. Also Sphinx support todo items marked with the .. todo:: directive.

Comment: I think its a bad practice. Doc strings should be by definition `code that is used, like a comment, to document a specific segment of code`. TODOs however are indicators for yourself or colleagues what to do with a segment, not about how that segment works.

Comment: If you put it this way it makes sense not to put them in docstring. I must confess I didn't think it fully through. Was just wondering why a todo wasn't found when put in a docstring. So I take it this is on purpose.

Comment: There arises another question when using todo items. Can I exclude files or directories from todo item analysis. I'm using a virtual environment within my project directory so all todo items from third-party packages are listed too. I'd like to limit the listed todo items to my project package only but as far as I can see there is no obvious way to exclude files or directories.

Comment: To exclude a certain directory from indexing you can mark it as excluded in the PyCharm Project Tool Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right PyCharm makes a difference between comments like

```
# Comment
```

and docstrings like

```
"""
My function does this and that.

"""
```

TODO entries are only looked for in comments. So

```
"""
My function does this and that.

todo: add something else

"""
```

wont work.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm supports TODOs in Docstrings since version 2017.3

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11040